# Simple hyperlink in GWT?

Tags: gwt

This should be simple, but somehow I can't find a way to create simple hyperlink in GWT. Basically, I want to load another page when users clicks on something.

[Hyperlink](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Hyperlink.html) seems to point to internal GWT application state only. I guess I could put the link in HTML code itself, but how do I create it in Java?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Anchor](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Anchor.html)
    this.add(new Anchor("www.stackoverflow.com"));

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for [Anchor](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Anchor.html).

Comment: you linked to the 1.5 documentation.