# GWT hyperlink problem

Tags: java, gwt

i am using GWT Hyperlink for Click handling.I used rpc for showing the records in a dialog box by clicking on that link.but it is moving to home page immediately and showing the dialog box there.Please suggest me the solution for this problem.

Comment: Could you please show your code - for Hyperlink creation and click handling?

Comment: See also [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767572/simple-hyperlink-in-gwt).

Answer (score 3):

`Hyperlink` should be used in combination with History (http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html) changes and not for click handling alone. When using `Hyperlink` the History token is updated, which will probably trigger the History change which will direct to the homepage, Next the click is handled which shows the dialog

EDIT:
Just as David mentions it's better to use the `Anchor` widget. Because `Anchor` is a native html element `A`, it's usability is better over using a `span` or `div`.

Answer (score 2):

I concur with Hilbrand, but recommend anchor tags in such cases.

```
<g:Anchor name="whatever">Click me</g:anchor>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this case I would suggest you to use **CustomButton** instead of **HypherLink**. For that custom button give some styles to look like a hypherlink. If you use label you cannot focus using keyboard.

Use **hypherlink** only if you are planning to give history support.